# WP All Import / STM Add-on / Motors listings theme

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I use WP All Import and Stm Add-on to import my products to the Motors theme Listings module. I can not import all my images added in the image gallery only the first image is taken into account. The other images do not appear in my gallery. Also I can not use FOREARCH because my images are not grouped in a single tag.
Do you have a solution to offer me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an image capture explaining my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOoOp.jpg)

[Here is an image capture explaining my problem
[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hITdu.jpg)